# grok/kv filter audit logs logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm learning how to use the grok plugin. I have a message string like so

`"type=CRYPTO_SESSION msg=audit(111111.111:111111): pid=22730 uid=0 auid=123 ses=123 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:a1-a1:a1.a1234 msg='op=xx=xx cipher=xx ksize=111 mac=xx pfs=xxx spid=111 suid=000 rport=000 laddr=11.11.111.111 lport=123  exe=\"/usr/sbin/sshd\" hostname=? addr=11.111.111.11 terminal=? res=success'"`

I'd like to extract the fields laddr, addr, and lport. I created a patterns directory with the following structure

```
patterns
|
-- laddr
|
-- addr
```

My filter is written like so

```
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
        match => { "messaage" => "%{LADDR:laddr} %{ADDR:addr}"}
    }
}
```

I was expecting to extract at least **laddr** and **addr**. I get matches using https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/. With these patterns

```
(?<laddr>\b(laddr=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b)
```

```
(?<addr>\b(addr=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b)
```

but the configuration fails to compile. I'm just going off of these docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html. I've also tried using a kv filter the issue that I run into when I try to use something like

```
filter{
    kv {
        value_split => "="
    }
}
```

I end up with `msg` field showing up twice. I'd really like to figure out how to get the properties from this string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filter?

Comment: with this pattern `%{LADDR:laddr} %{ADDR:addr}`, it would only work if your log looked like this: `laddr=11.11.111.111 addr=999.999.999.999'`. With grok, the pattern you're using has to match the whole log line. Though for a log like this, the kv filter is way better.

Comment: @baudsp I tried using a kv filter, as well.

Comment: use the include_keys option of the kv filter with just the keys your are interested in, perhaps?

Comment: if you want to use grok, use this pattern: `%{LADDR:laddr}%{GREEDYDATA}%{ADDR:addr}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its field split :

```
filter {
  kv {
    field_split => "&?"
  }
}
```

Did you try this, are you getting any error messages?